# Spring MVC controller won't respond to POST from a form

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, post

In short, I have a Spring 3.1 MVC project and my controller doesn't respond to the POST request when I hit the submit button.

There is no error, just no response.  The controller method is not being called.  I have a logger in the method that displays an INFO message and nothing is displayed (other INFO messages do display).  MVC is working (at least partial) because I get a response from a "home" JSP page, but nothing for a POST.

I'm including things that seem important; tell me if there's something you'd like to see.

Controller class:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/register")
public class EditorController {
...

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addEditorFromForm(@Valid Editor editor,
            BindingResult bindingResult) throws ClassNotFoundException,
            IOException {

        if (LOG.isInfoEnabled()) {
            LOG.info("In addEditorFromForm()");
        }

        // Form did not validate
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "register/first_time";
        }

        getEditorDao().saveEditor(editor);

        // New editor still needs to login
        return "home";
    }

}
```

WEB-INF/views/register/first_time.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="sf" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<c:url value='/resources/css/base.css' />">
<title>Register for DIY Doctrine</title>
</head>
<body class="center">

<h2>Sign up for DIY Doctrine</h2>

<sf:form method="POST" modelAttribute="editor">
<fieldset>
    <table cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <th><label for="username">Username:</label></th>
            <td><sf:input path="username" size="30" id="username"/></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th><label for="user_password">Password:</label></th>
            <td><sf:password path="password" size="30" showPassword="false"
                id="user_password"/>
        </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</fieldset>
<input type="submit" value="Submit Registration" />
</sf:form>
</body>
</html>
```

You get the `register/first_time.jsp` from this method in the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "first_time")
    public String displayForm(Model model) {
        if (LOG.isInfoEnabled()) {
            LOG.info("In displayForm()");
        }
        model.addAttribute(new Editor());
        return "register/first_time";
    }
```

These are the headers returned when you press the submit button in `register/first_time`:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/doctrine/register/first_time
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,sl;q=0.6
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:34
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie:JSESSIONID=08209E778F63429CFA031A1DB53491DD
Host:localhost:8080
Origin:http://localhost:8080
Referer:http://localhost:8080/doctrine/register/first_time
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.41 Safari/537.36
Form Dataview sourceview URL encoded
username:ngeorgewitz
password:1234
Response Headersview source
Content-Language:en-US
Content-Length:950
Content-Type:text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
Date:Tue, 24 Dec 2013 20:28:19 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

Comment: Where is the url set on the JSP page, the submit url?

Comment: @zeus If you don't provide an `action` attribute, the POST will be submit to the current URL.

Comment: Yes...and I'm guessing the problem is that this page has a current URL of something like /home.  If that is so, then the solution is to specify the action attribute.

Comment: @Todd Except, unless OP has a POST handler for something like `/home`, they should see a 404 or some unexpected response. They say they don't see anything.

Comment: @zeus @sotirios @todd I've edited the question to make it clear that the JSP page is in `WEB-INF/views/register`.

Comment: Where the JSP is doesn't matter. What matters is which URL was handled that caused the JSP to be rendered, ie. which request brought you to that form.

Comment: Look at your logs when the server starts up. Do you see your controller loads?

Comment: I think @ToddGibson is right, the mapping in the controller is on `/register`

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, you are correct unless there IS a /home (or /first_time, or whatever) handler that does not have a RequestMethod specified

Comment: @ToddGibson edited the question to show that `register/first_time` is launched from a method in the controller.

Comment: @Avi Yes, I see the controller and the mappings in the startup log messages.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis There is a `/home` controller and mapping.  It does not fire when the method returns a model of `register/first_time`.

Comment: We will need more details. On Chrome (or the alternative on other browsers) press F12 and check the Network tab to see what request is sent when you click the submit button.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis edited question to include headers from the submit button

Comment: Post the response too.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis The response seems to be just the register/firstime html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "first_time")
```

to

```
@RequestMapping(value = "first_time", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

you will get a 405 Method Not Allowed when submitting your form.

When you don't specify a `action` attribute to a `<form>` element, as you do here

```
<sf:form method="POST" modelAttribute="editor">
```

a browser will typically make a request to whatever URL it did its previous request.

You did your previous request, a GET, to

```
some-host:[some-port]/your-context/first_time
```

When you submit your form, the browser makes a POST request again to

```
some-host:[some-port]/your-context/first_time
```

Since you haven't specified a `method` on the `@RequestMapping`, it handles all request method types and therefore handles that POST.

The simple solution is to specify an `action` attribute on the `<form>`.

Comment: It took me a while to figure out what the action attribute should be, but I landed on `action="update"` and in my `addEditorFromForm()` method, `@RequestMapping(value = "update", method = RequestMethod.POST)`.  It turns out that the action give me a URL of `http://my_host:8080/my_context/register/update`, which I wanted so that my method could be in the `EditorController` class.